# Android el tema oscuro no se activa con MODE_NIGHT_AUTO

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estoy implementando que se cambie el tema de la app dependiendo si es de día o de noche, mediante `NightMode` de Android

Tengo definido los dos temas, día y noche que funcionan correctamente

Para activar el oscuro/noche
`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);`

Para activar el claro/dia
`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);`

Pero a la hora de especificar que active el claro o oscuro dependiendo de la hora del sistema, con el valor `MODE_NIGHT_AUTO` nunca se activa el de noche.

En el log recibo

> Could not get last known location. This is probably because the app
>   does not have any location permissions. Falling back to hardcoded
>   sunrise/sunset values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He buscado el error y me ha enviado a [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491960/android-check-permission-for-locationmanager)

Supongo que para obtener a que hora se pone el sol, debe usar la última posición conocida para el sistema, se debe otorgar los permisos para que funcione el tema daynight

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```